# What is the coverage of Google case law for New York state?

Tags: usa, legal

I can't seem to find how any information about what kind of coverage Google offers for case law, what the selection for cases is, etc. Does anyone have any idea? I literally don't see any comments at all.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and explain what this has to do with open data - a little introduction for the (international) audience? It sounds as if this is something regional/national as well, so the question needs a country/region tag.

Comment: Yes, but you still haven't explained anything else. I have completely **no idea** what you are talking about. Obviously others have, otherwise I would've voted this question as *unclear what you're asking*.

Answer (score 1):

"Complete state results will become publicly available this fall for California and New York," [Harvard Law Library Readies Trove of Decisions for Digital Age](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/10/29/us/harvard-law-library-sacrifices-a-trove-for-the-sake-of-a-free-database.html)

Comment: thanks for that link, but that's actually another initiative with a company called Ravel and has nothing to do with Google so far as I can. Also it's not clear from inspecting their website that Ravel is going to meet their target. So far they just seem to have a fancy video, unless the data is only available once you sign up. Seems deliberately murky.

Comment: Mmmm pretty sure this project will really happen - Jonathan Zittrain is no slouch. Not sure you read the entire article or looked here either - http://etseq.law.harvard.edu/2015/10/free-the-law-overview/. Why the "Google only" requirement? Google isn't the only source of info that a Google search returns.

Comment: I did read he article, and it said that all of NY and CA would be available this fall. It's Nov 11, and there's no signs of anything. The link you sent, dated Oct 29, projects NY and CA for 2016, not the publicly announced fall 2015. I don't have a Google only requirement, but my question was about the coverage Google offers since they have a project that actually exists rather than having a fancy video but nothing else. I don't like when companies miss their deadlines and don't admit it. I wish Ravel luck but I like to judge organizations by what is done rather than said.

Comment: can you point to any progress by Ravel? So far as I have heard, despite their promises, nothing has been made public.

Comment: Check out this blog post re: California case law being available and sign up for the webinar to learn more - http://blog.ravellaw.com/california-case-law-now-live